# Laravel - How to pass variables to middleware through route group?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

This is my route group,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkUserLevel'], function () {
                // my routes
            });
```

And this is my middleware **checkUserLevel**,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $level)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($user->level > $level) {
            return redirect('testUrl');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

I want to pass the `$level` variale to middleware from route group.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments from router to middleware in laravel 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437791/how-to-pass-arguments-from-router-to-middleware-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply pass multiple arguments into the middleware using a colon. Use it like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkUserLevel:some_value_of_level'], function () {
            // my routes
        });
```

Now, you can have this value inside your $level variable.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $level)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user->level > $level) {
        return redirect('testUrl');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This would help.

---

### **Edit**: 14 Dec 2018

You can also send multiple variables to middleware. You just need to seperate the values using a comma (,).

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'checkUserLevel:some_value_of_level, one_more_value_to_send'], function () {
                    // my routes
});
```

And you will get the value `one_more_value_to_send` in the variable after `$level` in the middleware handler.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $level, $another_value)
{
   $user = Auth::user();
   if ($user->level > $level) {
      return redirect('testUrl');
   }

   return $next($request);
}
```

For more details you can refer to: [Passing parameters to Middleware in Laravel 5.1](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/passing-parameters-to-middleware-in-laravel-5.1/)

Comment: @xEterno Yes, you can send multiple variables by seperating them by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 6.x you have to do this
add code like in your middleware

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next,$module=null,$right=null)
    {
        dd($module,$right);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

your route code like this

```
Route::get('/department/add', 'DepartmentController@addNew')->middleware('ManualSec:abc,xyz');
```

In Kernel.php register your middleware in the section of $routeMiddleware like

```
'ManualSec' => \App\Http\Middleware\ManualSec::class,
```

by calling the rout using url in my case

```
http://local.pms.com:8080/department/add
```

it will result is like:

[image]

now you can code in your middleware